# railsのincluded do 内にenumを定義している理由が分からない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`included do ~ end` で囲ったメソッドは[includeされた時実行される](https://qiita.com/Momozono/items/433a1a7d397bb62f076e#included-doend)と聞きました。
ここでenumを定義しているのはincludeしたクラスでこのenumを使用したいからだと思うのですが、 `included do ~ end` の元々の用途とは違う気がするのですが、これは正しい使い方なのでしょうか。
実行 = 定義と同じような感じなのでしょうか。
詳しい方教えて頂けると嬉しいです。

[class_eval do ~ end と included do ~ endが同じ動作みたいな書き方がされている記事もある](https://www.techscore.com/blog/2013/03/22/activesupportconcern-%E3%81%A7%E3%83%8F%E3%83%83%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AA%E3%83%A2%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%95%E3%82%92%E9%80%81%E3%82%8B/)

```
module A
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    enum status: { published: 0, draft: 1 }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` は `included` の中にあるべきです。これはそれぞれの行がいつ評価されるのかを考えると納得しやすいです。`included` に渡したブロックの中身はクラスで `include` されたときに評価されます。

`enum` の話をする前に、例として以下のモジュールを考えてみます。

```
module M
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  puts "foo"

  included do
    puts "bar"
  end
end
```

Rails console でこのモジュールを定義してみると、定義したモジュール自体を返すところで `foo` のみが出力されます。

```
irb(main):001:1* module A
irb(main):002:1*   extend ActiveSupport::Concern
irb(main):003:1*
irb(main):004:1*   puts "foo"
irb(main):005:1*
irb(main):006:2*   included do
irb(main):007:2*     puts "bar"
irb(main):008:1*   end
irb(main):009:0> end
foo
=> #<Proc:0x00007fd91d38a038 (irb):6>
```

そしてこのモジュールを `include` したクラスを定義してみると、そのようなクラスを定義するたびに `bar` が出力されます。

```
irb(main):010:1* class C
irb(main):011:1*   include A
irb(main):012:0> end
bar
=> C
irb(main):013:1* class D
irb(main):014:1*   include A
irb(main):015:0> end
bar
=> D
```

このように、似たような場所に書かれた `puts` でも、そのメソッド呼び出しが評価されるタイミングが異なっています。

さて、`ActiveRecord::Enum` モジュールに定義されている `enum` は、それ自体はメソッドです: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

したがってこの `puts` と同じように、`included` に渡すブロックの中に入れるか否かで評価のタイミングが異なります。

`enum` を呼び出すのはクラスの中で `include` されたときであるべきなので、質問文にあるように `included` の中に含めるべきなのです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 確かに `puts "foo"` は呼び出されていないですね。これで気になったのは `puts "foo"` が呼び出されるタイミングってあるのでしょうか。このクラスのインスタンスを生成しても呼び出される事はないですし。

Comment: モジュール `M` を定義したタイミングで呼び出されていますね。`M` を定義するためにはその中身を評価しないといけないので。

Comment: 確かに呼び出されてました！ありがとうございます。おかげで理解が深まりました。